# simply primitive permutation groups of degree $2p^2$

Tags: gr.group-theory, permutation-groups

I know that the only simply primitive permutation groups of degree $2p$, where $p$ is an odd prime, are $A_5$ and $S_5$. I want to know that: Is there a complete list of simply primitive permutation groups of degree $2p^2$, where $p$ is an odd prime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the sake of getting this off the unanswered stack... Yes, all such actions are known.

By studying O'Nan--Scott--Aschbacher, one sees immediately that a group $S$ that has a primitive action of degree $2p^2$ must be almost simple. Now one refers to this paper:

*Cai Heng Li and Xianhua Li*, MR 3210408 [**On permutation groups of degree a product of two prime-powers**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00927872.2013.823500), *Comm. Algebra* **42** (2014), no. 11, 4722--4743.

The main result of this paper includes as a special case the primitive actions of degree $2p^2$. One can now compare this to the lists of $2$-transitive actions to conclude which are simply primitive.

Recall: a *simply primitive* action is a primitive action that is not 2-transitive. Note that the paper above is impressively general: one can use it to get a classification of simply primitive actions of degree $p^a q^b$ (with $a,b$ positive) -- note that in this general setting one also has product action type groups, not just almost simple groups.